# Can StormCrawler crawl a file system rather than URLs?

Tags: stormcrawler

Is there a way to use **StormCrawler** to index files on the file system rather than URLs? We have 5+ million files that need to be crawled and indexed (with **ElasticSearch**). The index needs to be updated daily or more frequently. Other crawlers take 50+ hours to crawl the full file set. This makes update cycles too slow. For example, if you need to update the search index daily or more frequently it is not possible with other crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [File protocol](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/protocol/file/FileProtocol.java) available in StormCrawler. If you represent the files as URIs using *file://*, SC should be able to handle them out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. Also, What is the recommended way to scale crawling of million of documents making up multi-terabyte file shares so that the initial and update crawling can be done quickly?